# How can I manage the location of the "NavigationToolbar2TkAgg" toolbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, toolbar

I'm learning how to use matplotlib, and now I have a problem. When I create a `Figure` in "tkinter project" and give it a subplot, I use `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` to create a toolbar. This toolbar appears at the top of the graph. How can I set it to other locations, like the bottom or the left?

This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("I am a newbie!")

# create the figure instances
fig = Figure()
a = fig.add_subplot(122)
b = fig.add_subplot(121)

# figure1 has two subplot and figure 2 has only one
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(2, 2))
c = fig2.add_subplot(111)

# create canvas1
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
# put this to the top of the window

# toolbar for canvas1 (figure1)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()

# create canvas2
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, root)
canvas2.show()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
# put this to the bottom

# toolbar for canvas2 (figure2)
toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas2, root)
toolbar2.update()


# this function just to exit
def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()


button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the window that appears:

[image: the screenshot]

- Why is the location of toolbar1 at the bottom?
- Why is toolbar2 above the canvas2?

I want to learn how to set their locations.

Comment: Without knowing too much about tkinter, but it sounds like you might need to create your own window frame with a figure canvas and a toolbar.  In that way you can place the toolbar wherever you like.  However it will probably require quite some work.

Comment: It would help if you make an [mcve] and posted your code.

Comment: @Ajean ,@pathoren   Thank you for your answer ,and I just edit the question, could you have a look? : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` is instantiated by

```
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, window)
```

method `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg._init_toolbar` is called. It sets `window` as the parent widget and at the end of the method calls `self.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X)`. This affects how the toolbar is placed inside `window`.

By creating `tk.Frame` widgets for the toolbars, the locations of the toolbars can be changed.

```
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, frame1)
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, root)
toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas2, frame2)

frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

button = tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit')
button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
```

Since the toolbars are now placed inside frames, the `pack()` call for the second toolbar doesn't affect the quit button.

The method in question: [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.5.2/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py#L750).

Comment: Thank you !  WIth your help I finally solve this problem ! Also say thanks to @pathoren